# Regex for password that needs at least two of the requirements

Tags: c#, regex, c#-2.0

I searched whole web but I cant found any regex for this situation. I need regex that check password for if it meets at least two of the given requirements

The requirements are:

1 digit
1 lowercase character
1 special character (!?€%&, etc)
1 uppercase character

Comment: There are a zillion duplicates. Have you searched for them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is no free code-writing service. If you have some code that is not working or have specific questions, we will help you. See also [ask]

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes with "At least two of these requirements are enough for my password.", otherwise one could easily form multiple lookaheads. Thus, we need some extra logic.

---

Say, you have these three conditions `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and a combination of two of them will suffice, then we could formulate the expression as

```
a&b | a&c | a&d | b&c | b&d | c&d
```

where `&` stands for `... and ...` and the `|` for `... or ...`.
In terms of your requirements, this would be (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rAFskf/1)):

```
^
(?:
    (?:(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]))
    |
    (?:(?=\D*\d)(?=[^!?€%&]*[!?€%&]))
    |
    (?:(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]))
    |
    (?:(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^!?€%&]*[!?€%&]))
    |
    (?:(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]))
    |
    (?:(?=[^!?€%&]*[!?€%&])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]))
)
.+
$
```

***But***: instead of using this monster expression, do it programatically: check the stand-alone-expressions with if-conditions because the syntax is easier to read and understand.